# Why is ubuntu unable to install two programs at once?

Tags: apt

I tried to install two programs at once in Ubuntu via terminal. it says this.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

`Could not get lock`: why does `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` need to be locked?

I'm so glad if anyone can explain the application installation process for me. Also something about advantages and disadvantages of using a package manager like "apt" compared to the package manager in MS windows.

Comment: Well, if you have ever used an MSI installer in Windows, you'd know that it too can only install one thing at a time.

Comment: "consider to package manager in MS windows." ehm Windows package manager also only installs one at a time ;) And the reason "apt-get" only installs one at a time is because nobody  wants their system to get corrupted :)

Comment: Now that I think of it, every package manager I have encountered (`dpkg`, `pacman`, `yum`, the Windows thing, the Google Play Store) installs only one app at a time. More annoyingly, most of them even download only one app at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This can mean that other software, for example the Software Center, is doing something related to installing software. To avoid problems the currently active program has aquired a lock to ensure no other process can interfere (and therefore you get the complaint about `could not get lock`).

You can solve this by restarting the computer.

And to state the obvious:
Did you start the install command with sudo, otherwise it won't work either because installing software is a superuser activity.

Despite the comments on the question you can absolutely install multiple programs at the same time with apt-get.

This command will install three (arbitrary) programs one by one:

```
apt-get install package1 package2 package3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting here is not the result of trying two programs simultaneously but to access the underlying database from two different programs - there could be several reasons:

1. you were starting two software management programs (like Ubuntu Software Center **and** `apt-get` or `aptitude`
2. you were trying to install a program while a software update was running
3. one of these programs started with its task and got killed (by whatever) before it could remove the "lock"

What should you do?

case (1): stop one of those programs, always use only one at a time
case (2): wait a few minutes, then try it again
case (3): reboot to make sure that none of these programs is actually running, the try again. If it still fails open a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` to remove that "stale" lock file.